# i passing a parameter to URL from a command line execution but throwing error with invalid connection

Tags: python, url, python-requests

The Host value int he URL will be passed as arguments but when i print the URL , it is working fine but not executing properly as whole script.

Python script:

```py
import requests
import json
import urllib
import sys 
import os

host=(str(sys.argv[1]))

headers={
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }

test_urls = 'https://{host}/Thingworx/Things/PG.MonitorStats.Stream/Services/GetStreamData?maxItems=1&oldesFirst=false&appKey=0b858f3f-4ed0-499c-a4d2-9ad0fbc0da9b&method=post'.format(host=host)
print (test_urls)

def return_json(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

        # Consider any status other than 2xx an error
        if not response.status_code // 100 == 2:
            return "Error: Unexpected response {}".format(response)

        json_obj = response.json()
        return json.dumps(json_obj)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # A serious problem happened, like an SSLError or InvalidURL
        return "Error: {}".format(e)

for url in test_urls:
    print return_json(url).format(host=host)
```

Error Output:

```
Error: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
Error: No connection adapters were found for ':'
Error: Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?
```

Answer (score 1):

`test_urls` is a string (not an array of strings), so you're iterating on each character and trying to GET `h`, then `t`, then `t`, ...

And `format` on the output of `return_json` makes no sense. Nor does your `print` (assuming you're using Python 3, print is a function).

Also requests has shortcuts for "Consider any status other than 2xx an error": [`Response.ok`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.ok) and [`Response.raise_for_status()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status).

And... why are you dump-ing the JSON response? If you want the textual version, just return [`Response.text`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) there's no reason to decode then immediately re-encode the response.